# How to make reddit comment bot target posts contains specific text and link?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I create reddit comment bot. But unfortunately when I add this code to specify work of comment bot

```
    for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():
        # Check if the submission meets the conditions 
        if 'youtube.com' in submission.url and 'test text' in submission.title:
            # The submission meets the conditions, so enable comments
            subreddit.comments.enable()
```

bot stop working.

Full Code:

```
sendSlackAlerts = False
mybot = praw.Reddit("bot1")
subreddit = mybot.subreddit("test")
if not os.path.isfile("posts_replied_to.txt"):
    file = open("posts_replied_to.txt", 'w')
    file.write('')


def docomment():
    print("Bot started - Commenting every minute")
    randomposts = open("randomposts.txt").read()
    randomposts = randomposts.split('|')
    for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():
        done = open("posts_replied_to.txt", 'r').read().split(',')

           # Stream submissions from the subreddit
    for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():
        # Check if the submission meets the conditions 
        if 'youtube.com' in submission.url and 'test text' in submission.title:
            # The submission meets the conditions, so enable comments
            subreddit.comments.enable()

        if submission.id not in done:
            rand = random.randint(0, len(randomposts)-1)
            randompost = randomposts[rand]
            print("Replying to post: "+submission.title)
            submission.reply(randompost)
            for i in range(80):
                time.sleep(1)
                print(i)
            with open("posts_replied_to.txt", "a") as posts_replied_to:
                posts_replied_to.write(submission.id+",")
            done = open("posts_replied_to.txt", 'r').read().split(',')


def go():
    try:
        docomment()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nOk stopping bot")
        exit(0)
    except Exception as error:
        if not os.path.isfile("logs.txt"):
            open("logs.txt", 'w').write('')
        now = datetime.now()
        date = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        file = open("logs.txt", 'a')
        file.write("\n"+date)
        file.write("\n"+str(error))
        print("Unknown error, find the error in logs.txt")
        print('Waiting for 30 min')
        time.sleep(60*30)
        if sendSlackAlerts:
            slacktoken = open("slacktoken.txt").read()
            client = slack.WebClient(token=slacktoken)
            client.chat_postMessage(
                channel='alerts', text=f"An error has occured:\n{error}")
        go()


go()
```

I tried made reddit comment bot comment only posts with specific text. But it not working. Can some one pls help me understand what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

well I have a solution for you

```
def docomment():
    print("Bot started - Commenting every minute")
    randomposts = open("randomposts.txt").read()
    randomposts = randomposts.split('|')
    for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():
        done = open("posts_replied_to.txt", 'r').read().split(',')
        if 'youtube.com' in submission.url and 'type beat' in submission.title:
    # The submission meets the conditions, so allow comments
            subreddit.comments.enable()
        else:
        # The submission does not meet the conditions, so disallow comments
            subreddit.comments.disable()
```

Comment: not bad bro! but still... can you tell me how to comment only posts with YouTube links? Look like `` if 'youtube.com' in submission.url and 'type beat' in submission.title:`` not working